# Opencart, howto put style to individual product name field(etc set color, bold, underline)?

Tags: html, css, opencart, product

I want to put different color for individual products in Opencart.

I dont want to change the stylesheet css file for modifying all product names style. as the product name field in admin side does not accept any html code, it accepts it but it wont use the coding to show the wanted color like red. It only shows the html coding in products name.

does anyone has knowledge for this?

Comment: It would help if you showed the output html of the individual products

Comment: You mean your HTML code is encoded and printed out on website instead of interpreted by browser? Remove html encoding when sending to database values or when printing them out.

Comment: Also, let us know what page in the site you want to alter.  Otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: well, Chetan Paliwal answers to you before  approach 1.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.
I changed my catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/category.tpl line number 149

From this:

```
<div class="name"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></div>
```

to this

```
      <?php $newproductname = $product['name']; ?>
      <div class="name"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>">

<?php 
    $newproductname2 = str_replace('CHEAP','<font style="color:red; text-decoration: strong">CHEAP</font>',$newproductname);
    echo $newproductname2;
?>
```

I know it is a mess, but it works for me, because I only needed it to show my customers that what products are "CHEAP"

thanks to all off you

Comment: Maybe it could be in the product.php file too, that then is basicly same style in product page as in category.

Answer (score 0):

So lets assume you are saving product name as `<span style="color:red;">Apple Cinema 30</span>`

when it is saved do db it becomes `&lt;span style=&quot;color:red;&quot;&gt;Apple Cinema 30&lt;/span&gt;` so basically the html is encoded before saving to database

so when you simply echo the name its printed as encode string and then html displays it as `<span style="color:red;">Apple Cinema 30</span>` which you don't want to do.

**Approach 1**

So basically before printing the name by php you need to decode it using `html_entity_decode()`  so that browser can parse the html.

for example in `product.tpl` there is a statement `<?php echo $heading_title; ?>` which needs to be changed to

`<?php echo html_entity_decode($heading_title, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>`

as you might have guess this is a very painful step, basically you need to find out every place where the name is printed and replace it.

now comes **warning** : there are placing like tab title where that html will treated as plain text and therefore tab title will show `<span>....` **so we conclude this a bad approach**

**Approach 2**

same as approach 1 but instead of replacing the text evrywhere you can just replace it at `catalog/model/catalog/product.php` in the `getProduct($product_id)` function. replace

```
'name'             => $query->row['name'],
```

with

```
'name'             => html_entity_decode($query->row['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),
```

**but this approach has same problem as approach 1.**

So now that we have rejected incorrect methods

**Correct approach**

create a new database table with mapping of `product_id`,`language_id` to`product_name_html` in `product_name_html` save your new html title of the product.

now that have a two type of name, you can display this new (html) name where you want (obviously at places which are treated as html and not plain text), without disturbing the plain text name which is required at places like tab title, plain text email etc.

This will required considerable coding like first saving the html name from admin side to db, then edit `getProduct()` types of function in model files to grab your special name with along with other product details, then replacing the code at your place(s) of interest

Comment: For these approach I think, I will pass new DB table editing and adding. Or if someone makes good VqMod for this one.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to specify what is the value that you will control for these products, is it a general one like manufacturer, or a specific one like name.

Nevertheless here is a php code that you can use and i have used before for the same case but for filitering based on manufacturers:

```
        if(isset($product_info['manufacturer']) && $product_info['manufacturer']=='something'){ //some comparison
            $this->document->addStyle('catalog/view/stylesheet/style.css'); //route to you style file
        }
```

And in that file put the css you want to overwrite. This piece of code is for product.php controller, but you can folow this logic everywhere, this is the default way that opencart itself handles specific .css as well as .js for specific set of pages.

Hope i helped you.

Comment: I can Understand that script but does it work with wildcard? like the product name what is shown in category listing "Cheap! Apple Cinema 30". as the Cheap! word would be in red and in bold as the different stylesheet specifies. Does it make the hole product name red or only the word Cheap?

Comment: in what files do I use this code? catalog/controller/product/product.php? how about the product name in category listing is that the same file or different? and what lines to modify?

Comment: Catalog/controller/product/product.php is the one you should edit in your case, the line depends on the condition you will set, for changes in category listing you need to change also category.php file in the same folder.

Comment: I understand the files product.php and category.php but I cannot find the good place for your suggestion to add that script as it should replace the styling of some word in the printed text? 
You dont tell that, does that script work with other words in the product name? as I asked before. 
I would use "Cheap! 32inch television" as product name and does it replaces the hole product name styling or just the word Cheap!? 
I think, I want it to make only the word Cheap! in the product name red and Bold. 
I can make the css file but the position of your script is lost for me.

Comment: As this edits the controller it can not and should not be used for this kind of styling as this is a more general way to add styling in a specific page and not content of the page also you can not add css only for that part if you do not separate them in some way, in this case the whole "Cheap! 32inch television"  part will change color.

Comment: Yeah. I think I don't use this directly to use with controller php files. I realized that I can use that if sentence somehow in template file to show the red and bold decoration in category listing and in product details. As if the php coding can understand what I want, as the first word in product name would be the trigger for that if sentence and then to parse it somehow to the webpage when it is needed. It wont need to be in invoices or emails.

Answer (score -1):

In stylesheet.css modify the element

```
.product-list .name a{
    color:#FF0000 !important;
}
```

on line 935 or thereabouts.

Comment: i guess you interpreted the question incorrectly, he want to add a different color (and may be other css properties) for different products.

Comment: Ahhh...I thought he meant for the list of individual products.  Not sure that deserved a down vote though.

Comment: Yes.  Just one or two products should be for example in red and bold from 100 products in listing

Comment: @Steve that downvote was not something personal, it was just to indicate the answer in its current form is not relevant to question. i agree the question was/is confusing